# How to force libxml1 to ignore cert in file and use a cert I pass it on the command line?

Tags: saml-2.0, xmlsec, xmlsec1

I am trying to verify a signed XML SAML Response. It contains a spoofed cert in the XML.

I have the known real cert in a PEM file.

When I run

```
xmlsec1 --verify --pubkey-cert-pem  pubkey-real.pem \
--id-attr:ID urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion:Assertion \
--node-id DaavCk888T6_KR-Rtdm52CZSceG saml-req-spoofed.xml
```

it correctly validates it! It uses the certificate inside of the spoofed SAML request, instead of the known good one I am passing it on the command line. I know this because when I add `--print-debug` to the params it outputs the spoofed cert info.

Is there a way to force `xmlsec1` to ignore the certificate inside of the XML file and force it to use the one I pass on the command line?

I am running `xmlsec1` 1.2.20 on a Mac.

Comment: Same issue on Mac running with xmlsec1 1.2.26

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of struggle, I found out you can try adding `--enabled-key-data`, for example:

`--enabled-key-data rsa`
or 
`--enabled-key-data x509`

Either those should work. You can also try

`xmlsec1 --list-key-data` to see the ones you can choose.